# avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"

Tags: arduino-uno

I was programing the arduino and things were going great.
Then I plugged in another chip, and went to burn a boot loader.
(New chips) now, I get:

```
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
```

when I try to upload code to old chips, I get:

```
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
```

ten times.
I have tried reseting, and it doesnt do anything.
when I plug the device in,

dmesg shows that the device responds to my PC

```
[526199.130716] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[526199.149422] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043
[526199.149427] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[526199.149430] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[526199.149433] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 649343332353518022F0
[526199.149579] usb 3-1: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[526199.149766] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

IDE settings:
board: Audruino Uno
serial posrt /dev/ttyACM0
Programer: AVRISP mkII

I also tried AVR ISP

in the command line, I tried:

```
   avr-gcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328 -o Balls.out Balls.c
   avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom Balls.out  Balls.hex
   sudo avrdude -V -F -c stk500v1 -p m328 -b 19200 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -U flash:w:Balls.hex
```

each time, I get:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

How can I troubleshoot the Arduino Uno?
Is this thing broken?

Comment: You (or your IDE) are using the wrong command line arguments for an Arduino UNO - although connected via USB, as far as avrdude is concerned it is a **serial** device, not a USB one.  In the case of your linux box, the first one connected appears to be /dev/ttACM0

Comment: it is on /dev/ttyACM0

Comment: Yes, you need to make use of that information.  If you are using the IDE, try the various selection menus.  If you are using the command line, edit what you have now into your question and you'll get suggested corrections.

Comment: Ive tried variations. Im doing the exact same things that have worked previously. How does someone troubleshoot an arduino uno?

Comment: First, add yourself to the dialout group or whatever owns /dev/ttyACM0 and re-login so you can get the `sudo` out of there.  Next, which error message are you currently getting?  Are you still getting the USB one?  If you are just getting the not responding complain, that points more towards a bad baud rate, an unreset board, missing bootloader, or damage.

Comment: the usb error is when i try to burn a bootloader.
the programmer not responding is when I try to upload code

Comment: Sounds like you should describe (connection and command) your attempt to burn a bootloader.

Comment: Question has been abandoned without the followup necessary to resolve, voting to close.

Comment: I agree with @Chris. Because this question is needlessly complex. I'll re-ask the question with my answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Generated from IDE

Because this is a generic error, I'll answer it. I was getting this on STDERR when using the IDE:

> avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"

This is because in the IDE I was using

- Sketch → **Upload Using Programmer [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + U]**

However, I should have been using

- Sketch → **Upload [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + U]**

Comment: Ultimately the comments clarified that this error was produced when trying to burn a bootloader rather than when trying to load a sketch.  Burning a bootloader can only be accomplished by means of a programmer.  It is unclear what programmer was available to the original poster - specifically if it was one connected via a (virtual) serial port or one connected as a native USB device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton [new question with answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/16756/13972)

Comment: Evan, you deserve a place in heaven for this answer!