# How come the console prints error `avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"`?

Tags: arduino-ide

How come when I try to push a sketch to my Arduino I see this error on the console? The subsequent sketch does not work.

> avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"

I've already added myself to the `dialout` group,

> sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER

And, I did that after I confirmed the `dialout` group owns the device (in my case `/dev/ttyACM0`:

```
$ ls /dev/ttyACM0 -l
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Oct 12 03:15 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in the IDE I was using

- Sketch → **Upload Using Programmer [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + U]**

However, I should have been using

- Sketch → **Upload [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + U]**

Answer (score 0):

Try "Tools> Port:> then select your board" 
Make sure your pc hasn't assigned new com port to the attached usb (Arduino)